# Integration with the exchange server: propose new time for the appointment

Tags: c#, outlook, exchange-server, exchangewebservices

I am new to the EWS Managed API 2.0, and I am working on integrating a web application with the exchange server. My application is required to create new appointments and reply them via the system, one of the functionalists is to propose new time for the appointment. I can find the Decline, accept, Accept tentatively response types but can't find the response with proposing new time.

any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

EWS Managed API doesn't have support for "Propose new time" functionality.  But please take a look at [this article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn495613(v=exchg.150).aspx), to see how to implement it using the underlying EWS SOAP APIs.